# OS X right click / define on ubuntu and windows 7

Tags: windows-7, macos, ubuntu, google-chrome, dictionary

I have been an OS X user for a long time and really gotten used to a lot of features that Apple has to offer. At work I have to keep switching between Windows 7 and Ubuntu 15.04. One of the most missed features that I have not figured out how to duplicate is the context menu dictionary lookup.  Right-click on a word and this option appears in the context menu:

[image]

And clicking on that leads to a pop-up window with the dictionary entry:

[image]

I mostly use it within the browser.  The browser I use the most is Chrome and it offers right click "search Google for *selected word*", which opens up a search results **in a new page**.

My question is how can I implement a feature similar to OS X, that opens up a **popup window** with a word definition in Windows and Ubuntu?  Doing it in the browser would cover most of my needs but even better, is it possible to do this with the operating systems so it is available independent of the browser?

Comment: That Chrome feature is only available on OS X?

Comment: It works with all OS's in chrome

Comment: What I want is the 'define' in right click menu, which is default in OS X

Comment: here is a [link](https://maymay.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/cocoa-text-contextual-menu.png) for the right click menu and a [link](http://cdn9.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/mac-trackpad-tap-to-define-word.png) for a pop up window. The feature is not avalable in other OSs and this is why I created this question. Thanks @fixer1234

Comment: You're saying a similar feature is available in Chrome, and the Chrome feature is available in all OSs.  But this is something built into OS X and you want access to it in Windows and Ubuntu outside of Chrome?

Comment: You got it right. Rather than googling it. It would be a lot more continent to extend os functionality and have OS X like dictionary feature

Answer (score 0):

In windows you can edit the context menu
https://www.thewindowsclub.com/remove-click-context-menu-items-editors

then you could probably invoke cortana’s define word look up
https://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10-tip-use-cortanas-secret-dictionary/

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Providing the link for reference is useful, but you must also [include the essential information](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) in the post. Please [**edit your answer**](//superuser.com/posts/1335192/edit) so it contains that information.